# Migrating discussion board between site collections

Tags: 2013, migration, discussion-board, list-template

In our sharepoint (where I can only access the client, nothing from the server) we switched (or had to switch) from one site collection to another on another server. The two servers are running under the same version. While migrating most worked like it should (some things were transfered by hand, others automatically) I face some problems getting the discussion board to the new sharepoint. I first created a template including contents in the old sharepoint and downloaded it and then uploaded it in the new one. Sadly when I try to create a new app I cannot choose said template from the list of available apps.

My first thought was that it just doesnt work importing templates from other server but then I created a template from the categories list from the destination sharepoint (the new one) but again the template is stored in the List template library and shows the correct attributes but I'm unable to select it from the list. The only way I see a template in the app listing is if I create a custom list and save it as a template.

Is there no way I can easily migrate the discussion board from one sharepoint to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine the content is most important here. One way to do this, might be to export your source Discussion Board to Excel, then use one of the open source projects from Codeplex to import that content into your target Discussion Board.

https://spimporter.codeplex.com/